# Parsing only optional arguments with argparse

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-arguments, argparse

I'm running into an issue with argparse's optional arguments. I want to be able to set integer parameters on command line along with true/false flags like so

```
python3 create.py k=7 split=9
```

My issue is that argparse ignores the equals and takes these arguments as [k=7,split=9].  As you can see, they end up being strings rather than the integers I want. How can I specify on the command line what arguments I want to be what integer?

For the record this is what my code looks like

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('k', nargs='?', default=6)
parser.add_argument('split', nargs='?', default=0.67)
arg = parser.parse_args()
```

Comment: try http://docopt.org

Answer (score 0):

In `argparse` terminology, there are `positionals` and `optionals`.  The `?` nargs allows the `positional` to be not-required (optional) but it is still a `positional`.  Conversely an `optional` may have a `required=True` parameter, but it still an `optional`, in the sense of taking a flag.  Yes the terminology is awkward, but it has a history and we are stuck with it.  To avoid confusion I like to talk of `flagged` arguments instead of `optionals`.

The `=` input only works with flagged arguments, such as in:

```
In [68]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser();
In [69]: parser.add_argument('-k', nargs='?')
Out[69]: _StoreAction(option_strings=['-k'], dest='k', nargs='?', const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
In [70]: parser.add_argument('--split', nargs='?');
In [71]: parser.parse_args('-k=7 --split=9'.split())
Out[71]: Namespace(k='7', split='9')
```

With your definitions, `k` and `split` are still positional arguments, even with the `?` `nargs`.  They don't take a flag.  You have to invoke them with:

```
python3 create.py 7 9
```

With just one string

```
python3 create.py 7
```

only the first one, `k` gets a value; `split` gets the default.  There's no way, with positionals, of setting `split` and not `k`.  Values are parsed by position.

Comment: I had some trouble understanding the first part of your answer. Specifically the first 3 sentences. 

I also am having trouble believing there is no way to make this work. I have seen this done before in code, I just do not remember how they got it done

Comment: There have been SO questions about handling general `key=value` strings.  While answers vary in details, the basic idea is that you have to parse such strings yourself - split on '=', etc.  If that's all you want to parse, skip `argparse` and work with `sys.argv` directly.